# Rotate SKSpriteNode without affecting zRotation or movement

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode that is falling straight down the Y-Axis. I want to rotate the SKSpriteNode while still falling straight down.

If I use SKAction MoveBy:, it will start moving left and right on the way down because it is using the zRotation of the sprite.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: check  [SKAction rotateByAngle:

Comment: That affects the zRotation.

Comment: oh ok you want that the sprite turning on itself and nothing else right?

Comment: See, when you rotate a sprite, the y stops pointing straight down, and rotates according to the zRotation. This prevents the sprite from moving straight down.

Comment: How does the sprite fall? Via physicsBody and world gravity? If so, zRotation should not affect the way the node is falling. Likewise if you move a node with a move action it will move from A to B in a straight line, regardless of rotation. Please explain more clearly what you're trying to do and what you observe to be incorrect. Post the code you are using.

Comment: My bad, you are right. I had the pivot point set incorrectly. Thanks for your help.